# How To Create Apache Mod Rewrite Rules With Querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've looked though the similar Rewrite questions like [Need help with Apache Rewrite issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905648/need-help-with-apache-rewrite-issues)

but, it is not doing what I need in my scenario. I think I am close, just can't quite finish

**The current URL:**

www.OldStore.com/***some/series/of/uri***

**The NEW URL that I want:**

www.NewStore.com/catalog/***some/series/of/uri***

**What I have tried in .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OldStore\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.OldStore\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/NewStore\/catalog" [R=301,L]
```

This works at the root domain level, but I still need a way to also include the URI `/some/series/of/uri` to the NewStore

Answer (score 2):

You have to capture the full request uri :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?OldStore\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NewStore/catalog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Clear your browser's cache before testing this.